# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running. & I have tried manually installing as other answers had suggested, and nothing is working. I have purged and re-installed the latest as well as other versions of the drivers multiple times now.

Comment: Ensure your login has not selected a "Wayland" option (click on the little gear next to the login button).

Comment: What is the output of the command `grep -i "nvidia" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` ?

Comment: The output is
[    39.740] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event14)

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Why did you ask that?

Comment: @KansaiRobot In this file You can often find clues on what is going on. Look for lines that start with `EE` (error) or `WW` (warning).

Comment: Do you know that the driver is actually loaded? Does running lsmod | grep nvidia give you a loaded `nvidia` driver module? If not, then the kernel module (and thus the driver itself) isn't loaded. Does `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` give you a version?

Answer (score 1):

Check if Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: it is disabled. what does this have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This happened when Ubuntu update somehow messed up Nvidia driver during kernel upgrade to 6.1.0-1015-oem (Ubuntu 22.04). I had to execute these steps to restore nvidia driver.

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'`
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'`
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'`
- `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
- Check latest recommended driver using `ubuntu-drivers devices` (It was nvidia-driver-535 for me)
- Install latest recommended driver `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535`
- Reboot and run `nvidia-smi` to ensure that everything is working
- (Optional) Switch to Nvidia Performance mode and reboot

Reference:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/197141/6?u=abdulraufmujahid