# NVIDIA-SMI error when installing driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed the nvidia 535 driver on a new Ubuntu installation 22.04LTS, and got this error:

`Error NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running`

I tried the suggestions in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187427/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-in) and didn't solve the problem.  Can anyone help?

The Nvidia GTX3060 is the hardware, and the following commands were used to install the NVIDIA driver. 1. sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade 2. ubuntu-drivers devices 3. sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535 Thanks.

Comment: The Nvidia GTX3060 is the hardware, and the following commands were used to install the NVIDIA driver.  1. sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade  2. ubuntu-drivers devices  3. sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535

Comment: Go back to the 525 driver. I have tried umpteen times to install the 535 driver and it doesn't work.

Comment: What kernel are you using -- kernel 5.15 series? If the 515,  try adding the hwe package for the 6.2 kernel.  I've had no problems with the 535.113.01 driver on my RTX3080 (not the "...-open version).